# python, create nested html nodes. How do i traverse the Dom tree from a graph and find it's immediate children and create an html file from it?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup, graph, agens-graph

I'm trying to recursively extract the DOM tree saved in the graph Database to granularly rewrite them as either HTML, JSON or other template files.
The motivation I needed to have an easy way of extracting and controlling DOM nodes, rewriting them into any needed templating format which can be integrated into CMS or MVC development where variable interpolation is paramount.

My attempt using a recursion fails because I'm confused about what to use as the next node parent or child.

What I need to do is visit
having the following tree, I need to create an equivalent HTML file using for now either beautifulsoup or other utility.

```
   html
        head
            title
        body
            div
            div
                ul
                    li
```

With the following code, without a recursive function, I'm able to get the immediate children resulting in the value of:

```
|> parent Id: 844424930131969 --- parent tag HTML
    child id 844424930131970 child tag: head
    child id 844424930131973 child tag: body
```

or the following html file:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

How do I pass **`d`** to be able to be part of the next recursion where I can obtain its children?

```
cursor = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:node {tag: 'html'}) RETURN n")    
t = [x[0].id for x in cursor]
print(t[0])

def graph_dom(t_id):
    parent = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:node) WHERE id(n) = %s RETURN n", params=(t_id,))
    p = [x[0] for x in parent]
    pt = p[0]["tag"]       
    pid = p[0].id
    print(f"|> parent Id: {pid} --- parent tag {pt}")
    parent_tag = soup.new_tag(name=p[0]["tag"])
    soup.append(parent_tag)
    children = ag.execCypher("MATCH (v:node)-[R:connect]->(V2) WHERE id(v) = %s RETURN V2", params=(p[0].id,))
    for d in children:
        children_tag = soup.new_tag(name=d[0]["tag"])
        parent_tag.append(children_tag)
        dt = d[0]["tag"]
        did = d[0].id
        print(f"child id {did} child tag: {dt}")        
    # graph_dom()   # I need to add a recursive argument   
        
graph_dom(t[0])

file_soup = soup.prettify()
with open("helloworld.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(file_soup))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call graph_dom(did) recursively in the children loop .

```
cursor = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:node {tag: 'html'}) RETURN n")    
t = [x[0].id for x in cursor]
print(t[0])

def graph_dom(t_id):
    parent = ag.execCypher("MATCH (n:node) WHERE id(n) = %s RETURN n", params=(t_id,))
    p = [x[0] for x in parent]
    pt = p[0]["tag"]       
    pid = p[0].id
    print(f"|> parent Id: {pid} --- parent tag {pt}")
    parent_tag = soup.new_tag(name=p[0]["tag"])
    soup.append(parent_tag)
    children = ag.execCypher("MATCH (v:node)-[R:connect]->(V2) WHERE id(v) = %s RETURN V2", params=(p[0].id,))
    for d in children:
        children_tag = soup.new_tag(name=d[0]["tag"])
        parent_tag.append(children_tag)
        dt = d[0]["tag"]
        did = d[0].id
        print(f"child id {did} child tag: {dt}")        
        graph_dom(did)   # Call graph_dom recursively.   
        
graph_dom(t[0])

file_soup = soup.prettify()
with open("helloworld.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(file_soup))
```